# Bower 1.8.3 cannot find module 'q'

Tags: npm, bower, bower-install

I recently updated bower via `npm i -g bower` and it pulled latest version of `1.8.3`.

Now running `bower i` immediately fails with:

```
module.js:538
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'q'
```

FYI: Workaround is explicitly install 1.8.2 via `npm i -g bower@1.8.2`

Answer (score 0):

Not that this solves the exact problem, but if you look on the [Bower](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bower) package:

> This package has been deprecated Author message:
>
> ...psst! Your project can stop working at any moment because its
>   dependencies can change. Prevent this by migrating to Yarn:
>   https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/

They recommend you use a package called [Yarn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yarn)